# How to capture screen bitmap correctly in 16/24/32 bit color

Tags: winapi, bitmap, win32gui

I am capturing particular portion of desktop window in a bitmap and trying to print
BGR pixel color value. This captured portion of desktop window is completely filled with 16, 0, 16 color.

When I capture and print the data when my window color depth is 32 everything is right, 
but if my window is in 24/16 bit color mode then I am getting different pixel values instead of 16, 0, 16.

I am capturing screen left = 150, top = 150, right = 200, bottom = 200.
********************CAPTURING AN IMAGE FROM DESKTOP********************

```
    iLeft = 150;
    iTop = 150;
    iRight = iLeft + 50;
    iBottom = iTop + 50;



        /*

    HDC hdcScreen;
    HDC hdcWindow;
    HDC hdcMemDC = NULL;
    HBITMAP hbmScreen = NULL;
    BITMAP bmpScreen;

    // Retrieve the handle to a display device context for the client 
    // area of the window. 
    hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);
    hdcWindow = GetDC(hWnd);

    // Create a compatible DC which is used in a BitBlt from the window DC
    hdcMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcWindow); 

    if(!hdcMemDC)
    {
        MessageBox(hWnd, L"CreateCompatibleDC has failed",L"Failed", MB_OK);
        goto done;
    }

    // Get the client area for size calculation
    RECT rcClient;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcClient);

    //This is the best stretch mode
    SetStretchBltMode(hdcWindow,HALFTONE);

    //The source DC is the entire screen and the destination DC is the current window (HWND)
    if(!StretchBlt(hdcWindow, 
               0,0, 
               rcClient.right, rcClient.bottom, 
               hdcScreen, 
               0,0,
               GetSystemMetrics (SM_CXSCREEN),
               GetSystemMetrics (SM_CYSCREEN),
               SRCCOPY))
    {
        MessageBox(hWnd, L"StretchBlt has failed",L"Failed", MB_OK);
        goto done;
    }

    // Create a compatible bitmap from the Window DC
    hbmScreen = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcWindow, rcClient.right-rcClient.left, rcClient.bottom-rcClient.top);

    if(!hbmScreen)
    {
        MessageBox(hWnd, L"CreateCompatibleBitmap Failed",L"Failed", MB_OK);
        goto done;
    }

    // Select the compatible bitmap into the compatible memory DC.
    SelectObject(hdcMemDC,hbmScreen);

    // Bit block transfer into our compatible memory DC.
    if(!BitBlt(hdcMemDC, 
               0,0, 
               rcClient.right-rcClient.left, rcClient.bottom-rcClient.top, 
               hdcWindow, 
               0,0,
               SRCCOPY))
    {
        MessageBox(hWnd, L"BitBlt has failed", L"Failed", MB_OK);
        goto done;
    }

    // Get the BITMAP from the HBITMAP
    GetObject(hbmScreen,sizeof(BITMAP),&bmpScreen);

    BITMAPFILEHEADER   bmfHeader;    
    BITMAPINFOHEADER   bi;

    bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);    
    bi.biWidth = bmpScreen.bmWidth;    
    bi.biHeight = bmpScreen.bmHeight;  
    bi.biPlanes = 1;    
    bi.biBitCount = 32;    
    bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;    
    bi.biSizeImage = 0;  
    bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;    
    bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;    
    bi.biClrUsed = 0;    
    bi.biClrImportant = 0;

    DWORD dwBmpSize = ((bmpScreen.bmWidth * bi.biBitCount + 31) / 32) * 4 * bmpScreen.bmHeight;

    // Starting with 32-bit Windows, GlobalAlloc and LocalAlloc are implemented as wrapper functions that 
    // call HeapAlloc using a handle to the process's default heap. Therefore, GlobalAlloc and LocalAlloc 
    // have greater overhead than HeapAlloc.
    HANDLE hDIB = GlobalAlloc(GHND,dwBmpSize); 
    char *lpbitmap = (char *)GlobalLock(hDIB);    


    // Gets the "bits" from the bitmap and copies them into a buffer 
    // which is pointed to by lpbitmap.
    GetDIBits(hdcWindow, hbmScreen, 0,
        (UINT)bmpScreen.bmHeight,
        lpbitmap,
        (BITMAPINFO *)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    // A file is created, this is where we will save the screen capture.
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(L"captureqwsx.bmp",
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        CREATE_ALWAYS,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);   

    // Add the size of the headers to the size of the bitmap to get the total file size
    DWORD dwSizeofDIB = dwBmpSize + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

    //Offset to where the actual bitmap bits start.
    bmfHeader.bfOffBits = (DWORD)sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + (DWORD)sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER); 

    //Size of the file
    bmfHeader.bfSize = dwSizeofDIB; 

    //bfType must always be BM for Bitmaps
    bmfHeader.bfType = 0x4D42; //BM   

    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
    WriteFile(hFile, (LPSTR)&bmfHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
    WriteFile(hFile, (LPSTR)&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
    WriteFile(hFile, (LPSTR)lpbitmap, dwBmpSize, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);

    //Unlock and Free the DIB from the heap
    GlobalUnlock(hDIB);    
    GlobalFree(hDIB);

    //Close the handle for the file that was created
    CloseHandle(hFile);


    //Clean up
done:
    DeleteObject(hbmScreen);
    DeleteObject(hdcMemDC);
    ReleaseDC(NULL,hdcScreen);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd,hdcWindow);

    return 0;
*/

//#if 0

    HDC hdcScreen;
   // HDC hdcWindow;
    HDC hdcMemDC = NULL;
    HBITMAP hbmScreen = NULL;
    HRGN rgn = NULL;

    BITMAP bmpScreen;

    // Retrieve the handle to a display device context for the client 
    // area of the window. 
    hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);
    //hdcWindow = GetDC(hWnd);

    //if(g_hdcMemDC == NULL)
    {
        // Create a compatible DC which is used in a BitBlt from the window DC
       hdcMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen); 
       if(!hdcMemDC)
        {
            //MessageBox(hWnd, L"CreateCompatibleDC has failed",L"Failed", MB_OK);
            goto done;
        }

        // Get the client area for size calculation
        //RECT rcClient;
        //GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcClient);

        //This is the best stretch mode
        SetStretchBltMode(hdcMemDC,HALFTONE);
          // Create a compatible bitmap from the Window DC
            hbmScreen = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, iRight - iLeft, iBottom - iTop);

            if(!hbmScreen)
            {
                //MessageBox(hWnd, L"CreateCompatibleBitmap Failed",L"Failed", MB_OK);
                goto done;
            }

            // Select the compatible bitmap into the compatible memory DC.
            SelectObject(hdcMemDC,hbmScreen);

    }


    //The source DC is the entire screen and the destination DC is the current window (HWND)
  /*  if(!StretchBlt(hdcWindow, 
               0,0, 
               rcClient.right, rcClient.bottom, 
               hdcScreen, 
               0,0,
               GetSystemMetrics (SM_CXSCREEN),
               GetSystemMetrics (SM_CYSCREEN),
               SRCCOPY))
    {
        MessageBox(hWnd, L"StretchBlt has failed",L"Failed", MB_OK);
        goto done;
    }
    */


    // Bit block transfer into our compatible memory DC.
     if(!StretchBlt(hdcMemDC, 
               0,0, 
               iRight - iLeft,
               iBottom - iTop,
               hdcScreen, 
               iLeft,iTop,
               iRight - iLeft,
               iBottom - iTop,
               SRCCOPY))
    {
       // MessageBox(hWnd, L"StretchBlt has failed",L"Failed", MB_OK);
        goto done;
    }
  }
*******************FUNCTION FOR GETTING THE BITMAP RAW DATA POINTER***********
BYTE* Get24BitPixels(HDC dcDesktop, HBITMAP pBitmap, WORD *pwWidth, WORD *pwHeight, WORD * pReminderWidth)
{


  // a bitmap object just to get bitmap width and height
    BITMAP bmpBmp;

  // pointer to original bitmap info
    LPBITMAPINFO pbmiInfo;

  // bitmap info will hold the new 24bit bitmap info
  BITMAPINFO bmiInfo;

  // width and height of the bitmap
  WORD wBmpWidth ; WORD wBmpHeight;

  // ---------------------------------------------------------
  // get some info from the bitmap
  // ---------------------------------------------------------
  GetObject(pBitmap, sizeof(bmpBmp),&bmpBmp);
  pbmiInfo   = (LPBITMAPINFO)&bmpBmp;

   //get width and height
    wBmpWidth  = (WORD)pbmiInfo->bmiHeader.biWidth;
    int iReminderWidth = (wBmpWidth%4);                    
    //wBmpWidth -= (wBmpWidth%4);                       // width is 4 byte boundary aligned.
    wBmpHeight = (WORD)pbmiInfo->bmiHeader.biHeight;

  // copy to caller width and height parms
  *pwWidth  = wBmpWidth;
  *pwHeight = wBmpHeight;

  wBmpWidth += (4 - iReminderWidth);  // width is 4 byte boundary aligned, thereby increasing the width 
//so that it will be fully divible by four , it will cause some extra bytes to be filled in with garbage value
//beyond the actual width of the bitmap, we will be discrading this extra padding pixels data while processign each pixel.


*pReminderWidth = 4  - iReminderWidth;
  // ---------------------------------------------------------

    // allocate width * height * 24bits pixels
   BYTE * pPixels = new BYTE[wBmpWidth*wBmpHeight*3];
    if (!pPixels) return NULL;


  // get user desktop device context to get pixels from
    //HDC hDC = GetWindowDC(NULL);




  // fill desired structure
    bmiInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmiInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = wBmpWidth;
    bmiInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = -wBmpHeight;
    bmiInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmiInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
    bmiInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bmiInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = wBmpWidth*wBmpHeight*3;
    bmiInfo.bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bmiInfo.bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bmiInfo.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
    bmiInfo.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;



  // get pixels from the original bitmap converted to 24bits

    int iRes = GetDIBits(dcDesktop,pBitmap,0,wBmpHeight,(LPVOID)pPixels,&bmiInfo,DIB_RGB_COLORS);

  // release the device context
    //ReleaseDC(NULL,hDC);

  // if failed, cancel the operation.
    if (!iRes)
  {
    delete [] pPixels;
    pPixels = NULL;
    return NULL;
  };

  // return the pixel array
    return pPixels;
}
```

Comment: You're asking us to look at a lot of code with only the vague statement that it doesn't work as expected.  Narrowing the problem down and providing more details of what's wrong would probably get better results.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately I got the below mention post on StackOverflow.
Many thanks to Vodemki who posted this answer.

[Get Pixel color fastest way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515646/get-pixel-color-fastest-way)