# Scan BitMap for Specific pixel color, and give x, y location in c++

Tags: c++, colors, bitmap, pixel

I simply want to scan a bitmap I have in memory for a specific color given the RGB values of a given pixel, and if found, give me the x, y cords of that pixel. I'm have code here that stores the bitmap of the given window in memory, and works fine. But when I try to retrieve where the pixel is with a red value of 60, i get all kinds of funky values.
Here is my current code:

```
bool findColor(int x, int y, int w, int h, LPCSTR fname) {
HWND window = FindWindow(0, ("windownamehere"));
HDC hdcSource = GetDC(window);
HDC hdcMemory = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSource);
int capX = GetDeviceCaps(hdcSource, HORZRES);
int capY = GetDeviceCaps(hdcSource, VERTRES);
HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSource, w, h);
HBITMAP hBitmapOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMemory, hBitmap);
BitBlt(hdcMemory, 0, 0, w, h, hdcSource, x, y, SRCCOPY);
SelectObject(hdcMemory, hBitmapOld);
//Added
HDC hdc = GetDC(0);
BITMAPINFO MyBMInfo = { 0 };
MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(MyBMInfo.bmiHeader);
GetDIBits(hdcMemory, hBitmap, 0, 0, NULL, &MyBMInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
BYTE* lpPixels = new BYTE[MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage];
MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
GetDIBits(hdc, hBitmap, 0, MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight, (LPVOID)lpPixels, &MyBMInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
BYTE red, blue, green;
char* pCurrPixel = (char*)lpPixels;
for (y = 0; y < h; y++)
{
    for (x = 0; x < w; x++)
    {
        red = pCurrPixel[0];
        green = pCurrPixel[1];
        blue = pCurrPixel[2];
        if ((red == 134))
            std::cout << x << ", " << y;
        pCurrPixel += 4;
    }
}
SelectObject(hdcMemory, hBitmapOld);
DeleteObject(hBitmap);
DeleteDC(hdcSource);
DeleteDC(hdcMemory);
return false;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515646/get-pixel-color-fastest-way

Comment: Using the following code from this post: 
did not work correctly. I copy and pasted as is and used it with:
https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_converter.asp
And It returned 0 results with multiple tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `hBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMemory, hBitmapOld);`

That's going to overwrite `hBitmap`, you don't want that. You should change that line to:

```
SelectObject(hdcMemory, hBitmapOld);
```

Then you can use `GetDIBits`

Also you have already copied the bitmap to memory dc. You can use `GetPixel` to obtain the color. There is no need to call `GetDIBits`

```
HBITMAP hBitmapOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMemory, hBitmap);
COLORREF color = GetPixel(hdcMemory, x, y);
BYTE red = GetRValue(color);
BYTE green = GetGValue(color);
BYTE blue = GetBValue(color);
...
SelectObject(hdcMemory, hBitmapOld);
DeleteObject(hBitmap);
DeleteDC(hdcMemory);
RleaseDC(0, hdcSource);
```

When you are finished also call `DeleteObject(hBitmap)`

Using `GetDIBits`: 32-bit bitmap format is BGRA not RGBA, therefore the first byte is blue, not red. You should specifically request 32-bit bitmap or check the bit-count before treating the bits as 32-bit bitmap.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    HWND target = FindWindow("Notepad", 0);
    if(!target)
    {
        printf("error, no window\n");
        return 0;
    }

    RECT rc;
    GetWindowRect(target, &rc);
    int x = rc.left;
    int y = rc.top;
    int w = rc.right - rc.left;
    int h = rc.bottom - rc.top;

    int screen_w = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFULLSCREEN);
    int screen_h = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFULLSCREEN);

    HDC hdc = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);
    HBITMAP hbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, screen_w, screen_h);
    HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HGDIOBJ oldbmp = SelectObject(memdc, hbitmap);
    BitBlt(memdc, 0, 0, w, h, hdc, x, y, CAPTUREBLT | SRCCOPY);
    SelectObject(memdc, oldbmp);

    BITMAPINFOHEADER infohdr = { sizeof(infohdr), w, h, 1, 32 };
    int size = w * h * 4;
    std::vector<BYTE> bits(size);
    int res = GetDIBits(hdc, hbitmap, 0, h, &bits[0], 
            (BITMAPINFO*)&infohdr, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    if(res != h)
    {
        std::cout << "error\n";
        return 0;
    }

    BYTE *ptr = bits.data();
    //for(y = 0; y < h; y++)
    for(y = h - 1; y >= 0; y--) //bitmaps bits start from bottom, not top
    {
        for(x = 0; x < w; x++)
        {
            BYTE blu = ptr[0];
            BYTE grn = ptr[1];
            BYTE red = ptr[2];
            ptr += 4;
        }
    }

    SelectObject(memdc, oldbmp);
    DeleteObject(hbitmap);
    ReleaseDC(HWND_DESKTOP, hdc);
    DeleteDC(memdc);

    return 0;
}
```

Note, the process should be DPI aware in case user is not using default DPI settings.

Comment: I guess I should add I was trying to avoid getPixel() because I'm scanning a large number of pixels and that would be very slow. I was attempting to extract the RGB data from the bits buffer, compare them and if it's true, return the x y cord of that pixel.

Comment: GetDIBits will work if you apply the changes I suggested. You have to examine the bitmap's bit-count before proceeding. To compare different bitmaps they must have the same bit-count.

Comment: I've made the edits to my original post. I'm still getting crazy values. this is very hard to wrap my head around.

Comment: You are reading the bits the wrong way. Also you have no error check and you are not properly cleaning up the resources properly as I had suggested - see edit.

Comment: Awesome, this has helped me out so much and the code is working. The last step now is to figure out how to turn the Y Axis upside down considering it seems as though the bitmap is built from the bottom up.

Comment: And I found another post where you have the inverted function as well. Thank you so much! this has been a headache.

Comment: I made a mistake in the `for` loop for `y`. Bitmap starts from bottom, not top. See edit.